# Opencar 301 Redirecting issue with ?route=

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have restructure the website from WordPress to Opencart and so all URL has been changed. I am trying to redirect my old products page with new but it is not redirecting since OpenCart adding some weird `?route=` and so on..

Here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
Redirect 301 /store/products/old-item-name/ http://store.mydomain.com/new-item-name
```

It is redirecting to this weird url

```
http://store.mydomain.com/new-item-name?_route_=store/products/old-item-name/
```

I appreciate your great help.. million thanks

Comment: I have already tried that but that didn't work either. :(

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `Redirect` is part of mod_alias and everything else is part of mod_rewrite. The two modules get applied at different points of the URL-file processing pipeline, and in this case your request is getting applied by both modules. You need to move the redirect up to the top and stick to just mod_rewrite:

So remove:

```
Redirect 301 /store/products/old-item-name/ http://store.mydomain.com/new-item-name
```

and add this to the top:

```
RewriteRule ^products/old-item-name(/.*)$ http://store.mydomain.com/new-item-name$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for support! So I have almost 22 URLs to redirect. Do I need to add top line for each URL?

Comment: @pixelngrain not unless you can fit them into some kind of regex pattern, otherwise you'll need one rule for each. You generally want redirection to happen before your rules that do routing or internal rewriting, otherwise you end up with the problem that you're seeing.

Comment: I have tried `RewriteRule ^store/products/old-item-name(/.*)$ http://store.mydomain.com/new-item-name$1 [L,R=301]` and place right after `RewriteBase /` but still it doesn't work. Anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: @pixelngrain does the `old-item-name` end with a `/`? Is your htaccess file in your document root or in another directory?

Comment: Yes it does end with `/` my site is on sub-domain and `.htaccess` is in `public_html/store/.htaccess`

Comment: @pixelngrain If it's in the `/store/` directory, then you need to remove that from the regex pattern, see edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Last `Redirect 301` rules is getting redirected by previous `RewriteRule` rule. In general its not advisable to mix `mod_alias` and `mod_rewrite`:

Try changing the last `RewriteRule` to this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# your 301 rules from old to new
RewriteRule ^products/old-item-name(/.*|)$ new-item-name$1 [NC,L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase\.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(ico|gif|jpe?g|png|js|css)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This is redirecting back to the home page

Comment: Has `store.mydomain.com` DOCUMENT_ROOT set to `public_html/store/`?

Comment: Yes. That's right. Still URL getting redirected but the page is getting home

Comment: Ok rename your .htaccess and try to use full code from my answer.

Comment: Thanks anubhava but again CANNOT BE FOUND!

Comment: Hmm are you still getting `http://store.mydomain.com/new-item-name?_route_=store/products/old-item-name/` in your browser?

Comment: No URL is clean now but just not reaching to the page

Comment: Ok good, what happens when you directly enter: `http://store.mydomain.com/index.php?_route_=new-item-name` in your browser?

Comment: And I believe `store/new-item-name` is not a real file or a directory right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37612/discussion-between-anubhava-and-pixelngrain)

Answer (score 0):

have just had a similiar problem when migrating from Ashop to OpenCart

the old urls were of the format
http://www.example.com/p/productid/manufacturer-productname.html

and were being redirected to

http://www.example.com/manufacturer/

the solutions was

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)manufacturer(-.*|)$ http://www.example.com/manufacturer/ [NC,L,R=301]
```

hope that helps someone.....

note you cannot directly match on manufacturer as a redirect  loop will happen so match included the '-'